# How many elements are there in $D \times D$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic

Let $D$ be the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$. How many elements are there in $D \times D$?

Consider a predicate logic with one one-argument relation $P(x)$ and one two-argument relation $R(x, y)$, along with constant $a$, with $x, y, a \in D$. Give a model with domain $D$ for which the statement "$\exists x\ R(x, a)$" is false.

Comment: "How many elements are there in  $\{ 1, 2, 3 \} \times \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$ ?" Really no idea ?

Comment: Please provide the definition of the Cartesian product; it might help with answering the question.

Comment: @LarryB. - why $x,y,a \in D$ ? They are variables and constant; their interpretation will be an element in $D$. See [Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)#Interpretations_of_a_first-order_language).

Comment: The editing is not correct; please provide only Latex editing ...